# mod_fcgid: read data timeout

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

My application have a process that runs once a day and it takes more than 5 minutes to finish.

Before it finishes, I'm getting these errors in the log file:

```
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 301 seconds
End of script output before headers: index.php
```

I know there's several topics on internet about it, but no one solved my problem.

I have already tried these changes:

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 3200
```

/etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
  FcgidConnectTimeout 9999
  FcgidIOTimeout 2300
  FcgidBusyTimeout 2300
  FcgidIdleTimeout 2300
  BusyTimeout 2300
  ProcessLifeTime 7200
  IPCConnectTimeout 2300
  IPCCommTimeout 7200

  <IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ...
        IPCCommTimeout 9999
        IPCConnectTimeout 9999
        FcgidIOTimeout 2300
        FcgidBusyTimeout 2300
        FcgidMaxRequestLen 10737418240
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

After all, I'm still getting the same error after 5 minutes of execution.
Does anyone have any idea how to fix it please?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you edited the correct php.ini file?. It seems your application is being run from the command line.

Php files run from command line usually have a separate php.ini file. You can get the path to your php.ini file by entering **php -i** command from the command line.

Comment: I have edited both php.ini files. I don't know why still uses default value (300 seconds). Anyway thanks for you answer. I gave up trying to find out what is going on and I wrote a Java app to perform this long run process.